# For Dagger 2, Is it possible to have variable constructor argument injection?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, qualifiers

In Dagger 2, I could use @Qualifier to instantiate two object of same type with different arguments e.g.

```
@Module
open class Bag {
    @Provides @Named(LOVE)
    open fun sayLoveDagger2(): Info {
        return Info("I Love You")
    }

    @Provides @Named(HELLO)
    open fun sayHelloDagger2(): Info {
        return Info("Hello Dagger 2")
    }
}

class Info(val text: String)
```

And I could have them bind as

```
@Inject
@field:Named(LOVE)
lateinit var infoLove: Info

@Inject
@field:Named(HELLO)
lateinit var infoHello: Info
```

However, if I want to Inject an `Info` object with an argument defined at the Object declaration side as below, e.g. as below... (obviously below is not possible), How can I do so?

```
 @Inject
 @field:Named("My String that I want to send into Info as argument")
 lateinit var infoWithAboveAsArgument: Info
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is AutoFactory. Basically it allows you to inject some of the parameters and define the others https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory